# proj4's omerc projection (cs2cs) broken?

Tags: proj

When I project longitude -60, latitude 0 to mercator, I get the 
expected answer:

```
 
> echo "-60 0" | cs2cs +proj=lonlat +to +proj=merc
-6679169.45     0.00 0.00
```

However, when I project it to oblique mercator with very similar 
parameters, I get a very different result:

```
 
> echo "-60 0" | cs2cs +proj=lonlat +to +proj=omerc +k=1.0 +lat_0=0 +alpha=0.0001 +lonc=0.00001
-8416502.68     -4.68 0.00
```

Shouldn't the results be approximately equal?

I couldn't use exactly 0 for parameters, since omerc won't initialize there.

I sense I'm doing omerc wrong: what's the right way?

EDIT: I am aware that omerc might have a minor bug for alpha<0: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.proj-4.devel/5773 but this shouldn't affect what I'm doing.

Comment: Version 7.1 of proj/cs2cs accepts zeros for alpha: `echo "-60 0" | cs2cs +proj=lonlat +to +proj=omerc +k=1.0 +lat_0=0 +alpha=0 +lonc=0` gives `-8416500.44 0.00 0.00`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Snyder's "Map Projections - A Working Manual" (Pg 68) - "It should be remembered that the regular Mercator is in fact a limiting form of the Oblique Mercator with the Equator as the central line". This means you should set your *+alpha* to -90 or +90.

[image]

Comment: alpha=0 is more close to a transverse mercator projection.

Comment: Agreed. For readers' benefits - if you need omerc's _+alpha_ to be 0 deg, then use _+proj=tmerc_ instead since omerc's _+alpha_ can never be 0.

Comment: @RalphTee: omerc's alpha can be 0:   `echo "-60 0" | cs2cs +proj=lonlat +to +proj=omerc +k=1.0 +lat_0=0 +alpha=0 +lonc=0` gives 
`-8416500.44 0.00 0.00`